# How to test that a sequence generator will generate the expected item?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, stl, set, containers

I have a class `B` that generates `A`'s. I know that in a particular set up, if I call it 3 times it will generate a particular instance of `A` (`expected_a`), but I don't where in the sequence.

I would like to write some unit-test code like:

```
A expected_a(...);

B b;

std::set<A> set_of_a{ b.nextA() , b.nextA(), b.nextA() };

EXPECT_TRUE(set_of_a.count(expected_a) == 1);
```

But using a `set` requires an implementation of `A::operator<()`. `operator<` can be easily implemented BUT then I am writing production code to satisfy a test, which I don't like/want to do.

I tried with `unordered_set` which doesn't require `operator<` but does require a `hash()` implemented.

BTW `A::operator=` is already implemented in production.

I could use a `vector` and and iterate through, to manually search, but this seems a bit clunky.

How can I write this test elegantly without having to implement test specific operators?

Comment: You could potentially extend that A into a TestA type that only adds that operator on top of the actual class. That implementation would be specific to tests, and wouldn't appear in the actual production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use another container and `std::count`:

```
A expected_a(...);
B b;

std::array<A, 3> arr_of_as{ b.nextA() , b.nextA(), b.nextA() };

EXPECT_TRUE(std::count(std::begin(arr_of_as), std::end(arr_of_as), expected_a) > 0);
```

You could even not store them:

```
A expected_a(...);
B b;

int count_a = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    count_a += b.nextA() == expected_a;
}
EXPECT_TRUE(count_a > 0);
```

Note that in both versions this count that there is **at least** one `expected_a`, but there may be more, which is consistent with your `set` version.

Comment: but count is not a member of `vector`

Comment: @Ken I am not using `std::vector.count` but `std::count` which is defined for any type of iterators, its complexity is linear, unlike `std::set` which is logarithmic, but that should not matter for 3 elements (should probably be even faster due to `std::set` overhead).

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom compare function that is local for unit test:

```
A expected_a(...);

B b;
auto comparator = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { /*comparator code*/};
std::set<A, decltype(comparator)> set_of_a({b.nextA() , b.nextA(), b.nextA()}, comparator);

EXPECT_TRUE(set_of_a.count(expected_a) == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

GoogleMock has you covered with [UnorderedElementsAre and UnorderedElementsAreArray](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#container-matchers)

```
std::vector<A> expected {expectedA1, expectedA2};
std::vector<A> uut {b.nextA(), b.nextA()};
EXPECT_THAT(uut, ::testing::UnorderedElementsAreArray(expected));
EXPECT_THAT(uut, ::testing::UnorderedElementsAre(expectedA1, expectedA2));
```

It will test if all elements are in provided container in any order.

---

If you only need to check a single element from the set, then `Contains()` matcher exists as well:

```
std::vector<A> uut {b.nextA(), b.nextA()};
EXPECT_THAT(uut, ::testing::Contains(expected_a));
```